# FATAL: Module fusion not found

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, directfb

I am trying to build Linux Fusion for DirectFB. I downloaded it from [directfb.org](http://www.directfb.org) .

The steps are described in README. They are asking for modprobe fusion after make and make install.

When i run this command i get the error:

```
Module Fusion not found.
```

What are possible issues and how can I resolve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have followed all steps

http://www.directfb.org/downloads/Core/linux-fusion/README

and now still you getting that error it means

your `make` and `make install` were not successful.  Do you see any error messages on terminal after running make or make install?

If make and make install were succusfull then `modeprobe fusion` should work

**Edit from chat discussion**

Using

```
modprobe fusion
```

will try to find fusion.ko in /lib/modules/$(uname -r) but some how .ko was not there or not working after make install so

tried with

```
cd go_in_fusion_directory
insmod fusion.ko
```

worked fine...!!

Comment: If I am wrong,but I did not get binary configure for Linux-Fusion.

Comment: I tried ./configure --prefix=/usr and i got msg

-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: obviously i run the command in that directory only.

Comment: see my revised answer...!!

Comment: actually I don't get errors but warnings.Should I provide output of make and make install here?

Comment: yea you can paste it on http://pastebin.com/ and give its link here..or directly paste it in question.

Comment: output of make->
http://pastebin.com/2XXsp8Sf
output of make install->
http://pastebin.com/YLsAKUJN

Comment: From log its seems that it installing rightway. Have you tried to make entry for fusion in /etc/modules and reboot system..

Comment: in /etc i dont have file modules.What I have are directories modules-load.d/ modprobe.d/ mock/ and rest others.Should I create new file & add fusion there?

Comment: Even I do insmod it says Error: could not load module fusion: No such file or directory.

Comment: Which linux u have installed on your machine? which package you have downlowded for fusion?

Comment: I use fedora 17 & I have downloaded linux-fusion-8.9.0 for fusion.

Comment: Please provide some other way if You know.

Comment: do u have fusion.ko after make command at linux-fusion-8.9.0/linux/drivers/char/fusion directory? if yes then do modprobe linux-fusion-8.9.0/linux/drivers/char/fusion/fusion.ko and see what happen

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21498/discussion-between-mr-32-and-shraddha-k)

Comment: The link is badly broken ! I think directfb.org is no longer owned by Directfb. directfb.net looks more sensible.